Calculating the allocation needs for malloc(): should code use row*col*sizeof or sizeof*row*col?
Is multiplication order important when allocating?
Even if multiplication may affect things in general, what about common ordering concerns with allocation sizing?
data = malloc(row * col * sizeof data[0]); 
// vs.
data = malloc(sizeof data[0] * row * col); 


@Dúthomhas Note that the answer discusses how to prevent some unnecessary overflows.  For really large cases, C2X is to offer Checked Integer Arithmetic <stdckdint.h>, and could address your idea - once it is released.

What are the types of row and col?  Are they both sizeof_t?

@TobySpeight The types or row col are not specified.  Various applications often use size_t, int, ...

This is an Answer your own question.

In any size calculation involving various types, the final result should be <= SIZE_MAX before passing it to malloc().
Recall that the result type of sizeof is size_t, some unsigned type with range [0...SIZE_MAX].

With only one multiplication row * col, the order is not important.

With more than one multiplication row * col * sizeof object, the order is important when types differ.
Use sizeof object * row * col (multiply with the widest type first) and consider testing for overflow.

As the size parameter of void *malloc(size_t size) is type size_t, any multiplication product will be converted to size_t as part of the call.

Did the product calculation overflow an intermediate step?

How to prevent?

How to detect?

Will the product exceed size_t range?


This answer uses sizeof data[0] for object sizing.*1

int * int may overflow cases that size_t * int does not
A common prevention is the situation when row and col might have a less positive range than size_t such as int*2.
In this case int*int*size_t will perform as (int*int)*size_t.  The (int*int) may overflow int math, whereas size_t*int*int may not.
Example 1:
// 32-bit int, 32-bit size_t  
int row = 3000;
int col = 1000000;

// 3000*1000000 overflows int math.
char *data = malloc(row * col * sizeof data[0]); 
// vs. 

// 1*3000 uses size_t math, no overflow. Then *1000000 also uses size_t math.  Still no overflow.
char *data = malloc(sizeof data[0] * row * col);

Example 2:
// 32-bit int, 64-bit size_t, 64-bit double  
int row = 0x10000;
int col = 0x10000;

// 0x10000*0x10000 overflows int math.
double *data = malloc(row * col * sizeof data[0]);

// versus 

// 8*0x10000 uses size_t math, no overflow.  Then *0x10000 also uses size_t math.  Still no overflow.
char *data = malloc(sizeof data[0] * row * col); 


So by re-ordering we prevent many overflow cases.

Alternately row and col could/should be size_t, in which case the order is not important.



Even so, sizeof data[0] * row may still overflow
With large enough values, even re-ordering is insufficient.  Checks could be added.
If code has available a wide type that never overflows a combination of 2 of col, row, sizeof data[0]*3:
some_very_wide_type size = (some_very_wide_type)1 * row * col;
if (size > SIZE_MAX/sizeof data[0]) {
  // Overflow
  data = NULL;
} else {
  data = malloc(size * sizeof data[0]);
}

Otherwise check in steps.  Example:
double *data = NULL;

// 32-bit int, 32-bit(or wider) size_t 
if (row < 0 || col < 0) {
  // Certainly an error
}

if (col > 0 && row > SIZE_MAX/sizeof data[0]) {
  // Overflow
}
size_t size = sizeof data[0] * row;
if (size > 0 && col > SIZE_MAX/size) {
  // Overflow
}
size *= col;
data = malloc(size);

When row, col are constants, simplifications are possible (not shown).
Other functions
In general the above applies to other allocation functions such as realloc() and aligned_alloc()
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size); is tricky as some calloc() can well handle requests that exceed the math of nmemb * size > SIZE_MAX with either NULL or a huge allocation.  Some simple allocate per size_t of nmemb * size with no overflow check.  See Can calloc() allocate more than SIZE_MAX in total? for more ideas on this.

*1 This answer uses sizeof data[0] as it is easier to write correctly, review and maintain than sizeof (the_type_data_points_to) like sizeof(double).
Other possibilities include , sizeof(data[0]), sizeof *data, ...
Best to follow your group's style guide.
*2 It is possible that INT_MAX > SIZE_MAX, in which case the ordering size_t*int*int is still preferred.
*3 Code here uses (some_very_wide_type)1 * row * col rather than (some_very_wide_type)row * col as casting an object may narrow its value with no compiler warning.  True today that (some_very_wide_type) is supposed to be wide enough to not narrow row, yet later maintenance may undo that and the (some_very_wide_type)1 * affords the compiler a chance in catching that. I find (some_type)1 * a more gentle way to promote the math than a draconian cast.

Nitpick: putting the size_t second (but not third, etc) is as good semantically as putting it first.  I grant that putting the size_t first seems stylistically preferable to putting it second, though.

Is Then *1000000 also uses... in Example 2 a typo?

@user202311 Yes.  typo fixed.

Note that order is only relevant if you don't use explicit parentheses to force grouping, e.g. row * (col * sizeof object).

A simple solution is to use the same data types in the arguments of malloc. The most suitable data type here would be size_t.

@mabalenk Yes, using the size_t as the common type certainly solves the order issue.  Still overflow  potentially remains.

If you get overflow in that case, it means you're trying to allocate more than possible.

@Barmar Yes, a math product that exceeds SIZE_MAX is trying to allocate more than possible.  Hopefully that is already clear.  An issue remains as how to detect that overflow.


Is multiplication order important when allocating?

Only if the code was badly written to begin with, using the wrong types. In which case the solution to the root problem is to fix the types or use a better style entirely.
For readability's sake we should write the order of the operands in the order we plan to use them - "row major" or "column major".
I'll address all of this, but to make an informed decision we first need to establish if there's a difference between "row major" or "column major".

Regarding coordinates and cache memory:
One thing one has to realize before anything else is that multi-dimensional arrays in C have no defined coordinate system. We can have arr[col][row] or arr[row][col] and either is fine as far as the language is concerned - it's up to the programmer to define what manner of coordinate system they like.
However, arrays do refer to physical memory. And for an array arr[col][row], the right-most index (row) addresses individual bytes whereas the left indices (col) address multiples of bytes. This matters a lot when iterating across the array. We should always place the index that corresponds to the inner-most loop/most detailed operation to the right.
The reason for this is data cache memory. Since reading from RAM memory is relatively slow compared to a modern CPU, the CPU will automatically load our array in advance into data cache, which is a faster but limited memory closer to the CPU core. In order to do so most efficiently, there needs to be contiguous memory access, since cache memory has a limited size and can only store so much at a time. Should the CPU run out of cache memory, data has to be reloaded from RAM, which is slow.
We say that some code is more "cache-friendly". This is efficient since it goes across memory one byte at a time:
// good
int arr[col][row];
for(size_t i=0; i<col; i++)
  for(size_t j=0; j<row; j++)
    do_something(arr[i][j]);

But this in inefficient, since it makes jumps of col number of bytes in memory:
// bad
int arr[col][row];
for(size_t i=0; i<row; i++)
  for(size_t j=0; j<col; j++)
    do_something(arr[j][i]);

Functionally these may or may not be equivalent depending on do_something, but performance-wise there's a big difference.

Regarding malloc and implicit conversions:
Given the above prerequisites for writing fastest-possible code - which is also likely the most readable code - we should define our coordinates in a manner that makes sense for the cache. If we plan to iterate across row in the inner-most loop, then that one should be the right-most index of the array.
And so for a "mangled" 1D array, then for readability we should write coordinates in the same order we intend to use them:
col * row * sizeof data[0]

Now this might be problematic if col and row was defined with "sloppy typing", which is an informal term for when the programmer doesn't even consider what types they are using but just sloppily types the int type all over the place. Which can be problematic if we actually don't need signed numbers, or if we actually need smaller/larger numbers for whatever algorithm we are writing.
In this case col and row describe array sizes and then the most correct type to use is size_t from stddef.h which is a large unsigned integer and also the same type returned from the sizeof operator.
What we should absolutely not do is to re-order the expression to rely on Implicit type promotion rules! If we did write the code such as sizeof data[0] * col * row then that implicitly turns every operand into size_t, because the * operator is using left-to-right associativity. But relying on subtle crap like that (and not even document it in comments) is a cardinal sin! If we for whatever reason cannot change the type of col and row to size_t, then the second best solution is explicit conversion:
(size_t)col * (size_t)row * sizeof data[0]

And that's good self-documenting code, where one may suspect that the careful programmer did consider a potential overflow and has taken precautions.
However in modern C we should do none of this. "Mangled" 1D arrays where indices are obtained from a 1D array by i*col + row is a thing of ancient C89. From C99 and beyond we have the variable-length array (VLA) feature. And it solves all of these problems - we can allocate memory for a 2D array like this:
int (*arr)[col][row] = malloc(sizeof *arr);

All the issues with types are now gone. That style does however lead to de-referencing as (*arr)[i][j] which is cumbersome. For cleaner de-referencing as arr[i][j], we could do this:
int (*arr)[row] = malloc(sizeof(int[col][row]));

This is also without any type-related problems and what I recommend to use.
There are all manner of arguments for/against various styles of malloc, some are subjective and some are not as good as people think, as discussed here: How to properly use malloc? Including the "what if you change the type of the data" argument which is flawed, as shown in my answer there.
